# How to fix [objectHTMLButtonElement] problem in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry to bother all of you. I know, this question has been asked multiple times. However, I just couldn't fix my problem.

So, I've been trying to create a tennis scoring system that shows the score when you click one of two buttons, the win button or the lose button. I have a button where they can add their name to the scoring system. When one player wins two sets the match is over. I then try to print their name saying, ____ won the match. When I try using the variable that printed their name before I get something that says: [objectHTMLButtonElement]. I've been trying for a long time to fix this and I don't know how to.

Here is the code:

```js
document.getElementById("youName").onclick = function() {
  var youName = prompt("Enter your name");
  document.getElementById("youOutput").innerHTML = youName + ":";
}

let points = 0;

function win() {
  points += 1;
  document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = points;

  if (points == 2) {
    document.getElementById("finish").innerHTML = youName + " won the match";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="youName">Your name</button>

<p id="youOutput"></p>

<button onclick="win()">Won the point</button>

<p id="points"></p>

<p id="finish"></p>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I know, this question has been asked multiple times."_ - Then what do you expect from the `n + 1` answer on that same problem to change?

Comment: the variable `youName` is not in the scope of the `win()` function so, when you try to do `youName + " won the match"` the code does not behave as you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to declare yourName in a global context

```
let yourName = null;
document.getElementById("youName").onclick = function () {
    yourName = prompt("Enter your name");
    document.getElementById("youOutput").textContent = `${yourName}`;
};

let points = 0;

function win() {
    points += 1;
    document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = points;

    if (points == 2) {
        document.getElementById(
            "finish"
        ).textContent = `${yourName} won the match`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Please be aware that answers (and questions) must be in English here, in order to make them understandable by the widest possible audience.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about: you just need to get used to how things are done here; we all had to. Welcome, by the way. ;)

Comment: Moving the variable into the global scope is a) not the only change in your answer, and b) not the only necessary change to fix this. Both points should be explained in your answer.

Comment: And what's with those newlines in `document.getElementById("finish").textContent = ...` ?